# Use of “in a manner“ in different ways

Tags: adjective-phrases

As far as I know it is correct to say “in a better manner”. Can I use adjective after “manner” like:

> in a manner better

Comment: Well, probably people will understand you but "When an adjective is used with a noun, the usual order in English is adjective + noun" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjective-and-adverb-phrases/adjective-phrases-position

Comment: Notice that I've edited a pair of typos in your text, pronoun I is always capitalized.

Answer (score 3):

In English we generally put simple adjectives before their nouns. So if the entire adjective is "better", no. You should not say "in a manner better."

> "I wish you would cook in a manner better."

is not right.

However, if "better" is just the beginning of a longer expression, then it can sometimes be OK. Examples:

> "I wish you would cook in a manner *better suited* to sophisticated
>   European society."
>
> "These houses are constructed in a manner *better able* to withstand the
>   harsh alpine winters."

Comment: I was just starting to compose a comment specifically citing ***better suited** [to some more appropriate context]* as a perfectly natural usage when I clicked on the appropriate button to see that you'd beaten me to it with an actual *Answer!*

Comment: Actually, this is what i wanted to ask.